# Available fields are not visible in the Discovery panel

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have some indices where a part of their corresponding template is like this:

[image]

when I query the indices in the Dev Tools, I am able to retrieve desired data and see the above fields. For example

[image]

you can clearly see that `labels.state` and `labels.pipeline_version` are available for this specific document. I can even search for a specific field

[image]

But I can't see all fields in the Discover section (for example `labels.state`)!

[image]

[image]

Any idea? Thanks!

This is the output of `_mapping` API

```py
{
  "debug-2022.07.15": {
    "mappings": {
      "dynamic": "true",
      "dynamic_date_formats": [
        "strict_date_optional_time",
        "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z||yyyy/MM/dd Z"
      ],
      "dynamic_templates": [],
      "date_detection": true,
      "numeric_detection": false,
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "strict_date_optional_time"
        },
        "@version": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "event": {
          "properties": {
            "original": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "host": {
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "labels": {
          "properties": {
            "params": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "parentId": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "pipeline_version": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "run_number": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "scenario": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "scenario_description": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "scenario_detail_params": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "scenario_name": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "state": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "suite_name": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "test_id": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "test_info": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "test_no": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "test_object": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "type": {
              "properties": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "xray_test_description": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "xray_test_execution": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "xray_test_id": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "xray_test_id_summery": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "xray_test_plan_key": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "xray_test_plan_key_summery": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "xray_test_plan_summery": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "xray_test_step_info": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "xray_test_summery": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "log": {
          "properties": {
            "file": {
              "properties": {
                "path": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                      "type": "keyword",
                      "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "message": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "tags": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "debug-2022.07.13": {
    "mappings": {
      "dynamic": "true",
      "dynamic_date_formats": [
        "strict_date_optional_time",
        "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z||yyyy/MM/dd Z"
      ],
      "dynamic_templates": [],
      "date_detection": true,
      "numeric_detection": false,
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "strict_date_optional_time"
        },
        "@version": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "error": {
          "properties": {
            "stack_trace": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "type": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "event": {
          "properties": {
            "original": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "host": {
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "labels": {
          "properties": {
            "error_level": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "jira_project_key": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "params": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "parentId": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "pipeline_version": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "run_number": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "scenario": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "scenario_description": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "scenario_detail_params": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "scenario_name": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "state": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "suite_name": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "test_id": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "test_info": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "test_no": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "test_object": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "type": {
              "properties": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "xray_test_description": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "xray_test_execution": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "xray_test_id": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "xray_test_id_summery": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "xray_test_plan_key": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "xray_test_plan_key_summery": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "xray_test_plan_summery": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "xray_test_step_info": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "xray_test_summery": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "log": {
          "properties": {
            "file": {
              "properties": {
                "path": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                      "type": "keyword",
                      "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "message": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "tags": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and my indices

[image]

Comment: Can you share the output of your `_mapping` API of your index

Comment: which version of the stack are you running ? Also have you check your data view (or previously index pattern) ?

Comment: @Math-fort are you able to resolve issue?

Comment: @Amit-ESenthusiast yes, it is resolved here 
 https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/136515

Comment: @Math-fort great you can post here as well and mark at solved to help others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out here https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/136515

> Currently, on Discover page we render only first 500 documents (per discover:sampleSize setting) and field list is built based on this first batch. If fields have empty values in the first 500 documents then by default they won't be listed in the sidebar unless user switches off "Hide empty fields" toggle as here:
> [image]